# python urllib.error.HTTPError

Tags: python, urllib

I have a function that works as followed:

```
def pull_sector(sym):
    company_data_link = "url%s%s" % (sym,API_KEY_COMPANY)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(company_data_link) as url:
        company_data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

    return company_data
```

this function works 95% of the time but every once in a while I get a 404 error and this is not a big deal, but it screws me up, how can i instead of crashing my scripts pass something like 404 on the return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `try`/`except` and catch the error and do something else:

```
def pull_sector(sym):
    company_data_link = "url%s%s" % (sym,API_KEY_COMPANY)
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(company_data_link) as url:
            company_data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

        return company_data

    except URLError:
        return "404 Error"
```

You will also need to import `urllib.error.URLError` to run this.